# Oracle SQL - Calculating future loan

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to work out a SQL query to calculate the **Future Loan Balance** based on the following formula :

**FV** (Future Balance) = **CV** (Current Balance ) - **P** (Fix Repayment) + **I**    (Interest Capitalized)

**where **I** =  ( **CV** * **APR** (Annual % Rate)**/365 * D** (Days between Period))

Here is the sample raw data :

```
Account ID    Principal        P (Payment)    APR 
123           $10,000.00      $200.00        0.2
```

Here is the sample output that  :

```
Term    Account ID  CV (Current Balance)    P (Payment) APR  D (Days)   I (Interest Cap)    FV (Future Balance)
1       123         $10,000.00           $200.00      0.2  31         169.86              $9,969.86 
2       123         $9,969.86                $200.00      0.2  30         163.89              $9,933.75 
3       123         $9,933.75                $200.00      0.2  31         168.74              $9,902.49 
4       123         $9,902.49                $200.00      0.2  30         162.78              $9,865.27 
.....
N       123         <Term N-1 FV>           $200.00     0.2  30         Derived Interest    Derived FV
```

The value of CV is always the FV from the previous term (and FV is calculated based on the formula)

My  current **constraint** is that I **do not have enough permission to create Procedures nor Functions in my SQL environment**

It seems like an easy exercise on *Excel*, however I couldn't figure out how to do it in SQL without using a Procedure/Function ....

Comment: Can you create a table? You might look at how virtual columns are created in Oracle. Share and enjoy.

Comment: @BobJarvis Thanks for your quick reply. No unfortuneately I only have the read permission and not allow to store data in my personal schema.

Comment: Where does the `days` column come from?

Comment: @EatÅPeach The Days column that I can calculate from the Time Dimension table, or simply use "add_months(Day1,1) - Day1" (assuming the Interest capitalize every month.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Oracle 11gR2, then you can use recursive CTE.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/83a1e/5)

```
create table mytable(
    account_id  number,
    principal   number,
    payment     number,
    apr         number
);

insert into mytable values(123, 10000, 200, 0.2);
insert into mytable values(124, 7000,  180, 0.22);

with x(term, account_id, current_balance, payment, apr, days, interest, future_balance) as (
    select  1,
            account_id,
            principal,
            payment,
            apr,
            extract(day from last_day(sysdate)),
            principal * apr * extract(day from last_day(sysdate)) / 365,
            (principal * apr * extract(day from last_day(sysdate)) / 365) + principal - payment
    from mytable
    union all
    select  term + 1,
            account_id,
            future_balance,
            payment,
            apr,
            extract(day from last_day(add_months(sysdate, term))),
            future_balance * apr * extract(day from last_day(add_months(sysdate, term))) / 365,
            (future_balance * apr * extract(day from last_day(add_months(sysdate, term))) / 365) + future_balance - payment
    from x
    where term <= 5
)
select * from x
order by 2,1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/83a1e/5/1)**:

```
| TERM | ACCOUNT_ID |   CURRENT_BALANCE | PAYMENT |  APR | DAYS |         INTEREST |    FUTURE_BALANCE |
|------|------------|-------------------|---------|------|------|------------------|-------------------|
|    1 |        123 |             10000 |     200 |  0.2 |   31 |  169.86301369863 |  9969.86301369863 |
|    2 |        123 |  9969.86301369863 |     200 |  0.2 |   30 | 163.888159129293 | 9933.751172827922 |
|    3 |        123 | 9933.751172827922 |     200 |  0.2 |   31 | 168.737691154885 | 9902.488863982808 |
|    4 |        123 | 9902.488863982808 |     200 |  0.2 |   30 | 162.780638859991 | 9865.269502842799 |
|    5 |        123 | 9865.269502842799 |     200 |  0.2 |   31 | 167.574440870206 | 9832.843943713006 |
|    6 |        123 | 9832.843943713006 |     200 |  0.2 |   31 | 167.023650550741 | 9799.867594263747 |
|    1 |        124 |              7000 |     180 | 0.22 |   31 | 130.794520547945 | 6950.794520547946 |
|    2 |        124 | 6950.794520547946 |     180 | 0.22 |   30 | 125.685599549634 | 6896.480120097579 |
|    3 |        124 | 6896.480120097579 |     180 | 0.22 |   31 | 128.860258682371 | 6845.340378779951 |
|    4 |        124 | 6845.340378779951 |     180 | 0.22 |   30 | 123.778757534103 | 6789.119136314053 |
|    5 |        124 | 6789.119136314053 |     180 | 0.22 |   31 | 126.854226053868 | 6735.973362367922 |
|    6 |        124 | 6735.973362367922 |     180 | 0.22 |   31 | 125.861200907806 | 6681.834563275728 |
```

The first part of the UNION query selects the data from the table, assigns term number as 1, calculates the number of days for the current month, calculates interest and future balance.

The second part of the query iteratively calculates the same set of data, based on the result of the calculation of the previous step. This continues as long as the `where clause` is satisfied, with which you can limit the number of terms.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use MODEL clause.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/83a1e/11)

```
WITH x (term, account_id, current_balance, payment, apr, days, interest, future_balance)
     AS (SELECT 1,
                account_id,
                principal,
                payment,
                apr,
                EXTRACT (DAY FROM LAST_DAY (SYSDATE)),
                principal * apr * EXTRACT (DAY FROM LAST_DAY (SYSDATE)) / 365,
                  (  principal * apr * EXTRACT (DAY FROM LAST_DAY (SYSDATE)) / 365)
                + principal
                - payment
           FROM mytable)
SELECT *
  FROM x
MODEL
   PARTITION BY (account_id)
   DIMENSION BY (term)
   MEASURES (current_balance, payment, apr, days, interest, future_balance)
   RULES
      ITERATE (4)                                                                           --number of terms to be generated
      (current_balance [FOR term FROM 2 TO 5 INCREMENT 1] = future_balance[CV (term) - 1],  --range of terms to generated
      payment [term] = payment[1],
      apr [term] = apr[1],
      days [term] = EXTRACT (DAY FROM LAST_DAY (ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, CV (term) - 1))),
      interest [term] =
              current_balance[CV (term)] * apr[CV (term)] * days[CV (term)] / 365,
      future_balance [term] = interest[CV (term)] - payment[CV (term)] + current_balance[CV (term)])
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/83a1e/11/0)**:

```
| ACCOUNT_ID | TERM |   CURRENT_BALANCE | PAYMENT |  APR | DAYS |         INTEREST |    FUTURE_BALANCE |
|------------|------|-------------------|---------|------|------|------------------|-------------------|
|        123 |    1 |             10000 |     200 |  0.2 |   31 |  169.86301369863 |  9969.86301369863 |
|        123 |    2 |  9969.86301369863 |     200 |  0.2 |   30 | 163.888159129293 | 9933.751172827922 |
|        123 |    3 | 9933.751172827922 |     200 |  0.2 |   31 | 168.737691154885 | 9902.488863982808 |
|        123 |    4 | 9902.488863982808 |     200 |  0.2 |   30 | 162.780638859991 | 9865.269502842799 |
|        123 |    5 | 9865.269502842799 |     200 |  0.2 |   31 | 167.574440870206 | 9832.843943713006 |
|        124 |    1 |              7000 |     180 | 0.22 |   31 | 130.794520547945 | 6950.794520547946 |
|        124 |    2 | 6950.794520547946 |     180 | 0.22 |   30 | 125.685599549634 | 6896.480120097579 |
|        124 |    3 | 6896.480120097579 |     180 | 0.22 |   31 | 128.860258682371 | 6845.340378779951 |
|        124 |    4 | 6845.340378779951 |     180 | 0.22 |   30 | 123.778757534103 | 6789.119136314053 |
|        124 |    5 | 6789.119136314053 |     180 | 0.22 |   31 | 126.854226053868 | 6735.973362367922 |
```

It might look daunting at first, but I have used exactly the same calculations as in recursive cte. If you go through the [White paper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/bi-foundation/10gr1-twp-bi-dw-sqlmodel-131067.pdf), you'll get better understanding of each clause.

Also, this works in earlier versions of Oracle too.

Comment: Thanks !! Really love this Model clause I believe the Model approach should work more efficient than the recursive With clause.